# Как добавить Footer в RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android

Как сделать так чтобы RecyclerView менял размер списка, тобишь сжимался.

Дело в том что после добавления RecyclerView я добавил еще и обычный view (Сделал что то подобие Footer для RecyclerView).

Когда удаляешь из RecyclerView какой то элемент то он удаляется. Но значение Height не изменяется. И получается что Viewшка который под RecyclerView  лежит. Он не двигается.

Нашел такой метод hasfixedsize он поможет решить мою проблему или есть что - то другое?

Comment: hasfixedsize тут не поможет. Изменить размер RecyclerView можно только на к-л фиксированную величину. Т.е. сложные расчёты нужны и это не будет верным решением. Стандартными компонентами такое не реализовать. Вам придётся вешать слушатель скрола и пилить очень охр*ненно сложные расчёты для динамического позиционирования футера в зависимости от, наверное, того, является ли последний видимый элемент последним вообще и его расположения относительно нижнего края экрана.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ужджас!. А как тогда добавить footer? В лист вью 2 строчки и все

Comment: Проблема в том, что вы не футер описали. Футер намертво приклеплён должен быть к низу экрана и не должен двигаться. Единственный выход - городить аццкую прорву кода с аццкими расчётами. Я однажды пытался найти готовое решение такой задачи и не нашёл. В итоге пилить не стал

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вы чего тут народ пугаете?

Comment: Гляньте вот сюда. Вам надо просто использовать библиотеку версии **23.2.1** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649406/nested-recycler-view-height-doesnt-wrap-its-content

Comment: @Flippy, я посмотрел ссылку, но не увидел там решения заявленной проблемы...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ну не знаю. Я уже отвечал на такого типа вопрос и в ответе оставил ссылку на этот вопрос. Получил галочку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно добавить футер как последний элемент самого RecyclerView. Можно выделить новый класс RecyclerItem с булевым полем isFooter, обернуть все итемы в него, положить в массив и в конце добавить recyclerItem с isFooter = true. Получившийся массив использовать для инициализации адаптера. Затем надо описать альтернативный макет для футера, например footer_item.xml и переопределить getItemViewType() адаптера вроде:

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return items.get(position).isFooter ? 1 : 0;
    }
```

в onCreateViewHolder() адаптера ввести условие, при котором если viewType элемента равен 1 (isFooter == true), привязывать к холдеру соответствующий макет:

```
@Override    
public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RelativeLayout itemLayout;
        switch (viewType) {
            case 0:
                itemLayout = (RelativeLayout)LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.task_item, parent, false);
                break;
            case 1:
                itemLayout = (RelativeLayout)LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.footer_item, parent, false);
        }
        return new ViewHolder(itemLayout, viewType);
    }
```

ну и в onBindViewHolder() аналогично привязывать данные в зависимости от типа элемента:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    switch (holder.viewType) {
        case 0:
            //для обычного элемента
            break;
        case 1:
            //для футера
    }
}
```

Comment: Представленный вами код не расположит последний элемент списка внизу экрана если остальные элементы на экран не помещаются

Comment: @ЮрийСпб, автору как раз и надо футер который всегда будет под списком

Comment: @ЮрийСпб, да, это не секрет.

Comment: ООО то что надо ,  всем спасибо за помощь спасибо)))